# Is there a limit to how many iOS devices I can synch with iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios

I've heard about the 5 computer limit.
I'm wondering if iOS devices are included in that or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit to how many iOS devices you can sync with iTunes.

The 5 computer limit is how many computers you can have authorized simultaneously with iTunes.

Comment: You can always deauthorize other computers from iTunes Advanced -> Deauthorize

Comment: @palaniraja not always. only once a year.

Comment: @Cawas - I think that has changed and you can deauthorize any time.

Comment: Rob, [you're wrong](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1420). But I were wrong too. I thought and meant about the *deauthorize all* process, but that might not be what palaniraja meant. Regardless, the steps he gave can be repeated as many times as you want, as long as you have *access* to that computer.

Comment: Yes, Cawas is the winner. You can deauthorize an individual computer as often as you'd like, but you can only deauthorize all annually. You'd really only do that when you've had to reinstall your OS, forgot to deauthorize the machine, and already had all the authorizations used. So almost never.

Comment: Does the answer to this question change now that a Mac/PC is just a device with the new iCloud way of things?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this has changed now.  Apple updated their policy in August '11.
http://applenapps.com/apple_news/apple-quietly-updates-itunes-policy-to-reduce-the-number-of-authorized-devices-per-account.html

Answer (score 1):

I've had no issues syncing 300 devices with one library.

Other than disk space to track the backups of each device, your time and money, I don't think there is any pre-defined limit.

Comment: 300 iOS devices? Either you are super-rich or you a really good reason to be using 300 devices :)

Comment: My employer funded these activities. :-) We managed substantially more than 300 devices - that's just the max we had connected to one single mac over a normal week's span.

Answer (score 0):

No, iTunes has no limitations for iOS devices. You can use as many devices to sync you want.